# Notice Array to string conversion in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, notice

I was working on a project in php earlier and got the notice the I was converting an array to a string. I was wondering if there's a way around the notice?

```
if(isset($_POST['acceptrequest' . $user_from])) {
    $get_friend_check = mysql_query("SELECT friend_array FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
    $get_friend_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_friend_check);
    $friend_array = $get_friend_row['friend_array'];
    $friendArray_explode = explode(",",$friend_array);
    echo $friendArray_explode;
}
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: `echo $friendArray_explode;`  Your call to `explode()` returned an array into `$friendArray_explode` which you then attempt to echo out as though it were a string.

Comment: var_dump($friendArray_explode) if you are just trying to see the results.  There are actually a couple things wrong with your code.  You are leveraging the old MySQL commands which are/have been deprecated.  You should switch to the mysqli commands instead. ( http://www.php.net//manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php ).  The fact that you are concatenating together your query instead of using a prepared statement (http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) you do indeed open yourself to a SQL Injection attack, unless you strictly control $user.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I want to be able to see "Array", but not the notice.

Comment: @user3720306: You want to see the word "Array" output (because of the implicit array to string conversion), but suppress the E_NOTICE? Really? There are better ways, if that is your intention.

Comment: @w3d no, I just want to see it for now, then I'll move on with what I want to do with the array.

Comment: Rather than suppress the notice, you could write: `echo (is_array($friendArray_explode) ? 'Array' : 'Error');`. Although `var_dump()`, as mentioned above, would normally be preferable if you are debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You should use another MySQL driver: MySQLi or PDO, since the basic MySQL driver is deprecated and vulnerable against SQL injection.

You should use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

```
$selectFriendsStatement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT friend_array FROM users WHERE username=?');
$selectFriendsStatement->execute(array($user));
```

instead of

```
$get_friend_check = mysql_query("SELECT friend_array FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
```

You should use the `camelCase` or `underscore_case` [consistently by the variable names](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/). So use `$friend_array_explode` instead of `$friendArray_explode`.

You should validate your postData before doing anything with it.

You should use aggregate functions like `GROUP_CONCAT()` and add another table for the friends by 1:n or n:m relations instead of storing them as an array.

You should add special quotes around table and column names, and you should prefix your MySQL column names to avoid naming collisions:

```
`users`.`name`
```

instead of `username`.

You should give meaningful variable, function, class names. For example `selectFriendsResult` instead of `get_friend_check`.

You should use fetch column when you want fetch only a single column, instead of fetch assoc.

Comment: Note: `explode` works just fine on UTF-8 strings, no problems whatsoever.

Comment: As long as the string is not malformed UTF-8. I guess in this case that scenario is not possible. Thanks!

Comment: "use camelCase ... for the variable names" - variable names in the PHP or column names in the database? Why?

Comment: @w3d As far as I know MySQL naming convention is underscore case, because the camelCase is filesystem dependent by that. So ofc. I meant PHP. I checked PSR-1, which says the vairable naming is up to you until you use it consistently. So the camelCase was my preferred style, but there is still problem in the code by `$friendArray_explode`.